# Land sale data Singapore

Tags: land, singapore

I'm trying to get historical records of land sale in Singapore.

(For example, with the data it should be able to answer the question of whether Varsity Park sold land to The Stellar (or even vice versa)  at the west coast area. And the details of the sale.)

What are some good source/s?